# Using setImageDrawable to draw Dynamic icon

Tags: android

There is a code inside Android SDK Api Demo

```
i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
final int w = (int) (64 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 2f);
i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(w, w));
```

can someone explain this code ? havnt found anything on web.

There is google doc that mention "setImageDrawable"  is for draw something on screen
And alsoe "GetPackageManager" for Returning PackageManager instance to find global package information.
now problem is i cant find the list of icon in project folder and plus that , how can i change it show my icon instead and add event for clicking them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to the code u have postet, the first line, there u load the icon and set it.

the second is for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this view, the FIT_CENTER scale it center of the screen.

the third, u calculate the width and in the fourth u set it to the imageview (set the size).

the icons u can find in the sdk folder. (\path-to-your-android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res)

to load you'r own icon use this:

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

and the listener:

```
    imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
               if (v.equals(imageView)) {
                  // you'r code here
               }
           }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer , one more little question , how can i find the icons list that "getPackageManager" routing to it ?

Comment: i think thats the default icons there u can find on this path: (\path-to-your-android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res. I'm not sure cause i don't have a running android sdk on this mashine i'm currently writing

Answer (score 2):

As of June, 2021, the answer by Manu Zi is now deprecated. In order to achieve the same, you would have to use `ContextCompat` as shown below.

In a fragment, use the following:

```
setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.icon))
```

If your code is in an activity, use the code below:

```
setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon))
```

Happy coding!!!